# Create Multi Array Json File in PHP

Tags: php, json

In My Web Application I am Using Json. I Need to create following Format of Json File in PHP.

```
{
    "title": "A cool blog post",
    "clicks": 4000,
    "children": null,
    "published": true,
    "comments": [
        {
            "author": "Mister X",
            "message": "A really cool posting"
        },
        {
            "author": "Misrer Y",
            "message": "It's me again!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any codeexamples? [json_encode($array)](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php) might be just what you are looking for tho. - Please keep in mind that Stackoverflow is a Website where people help you, not do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

- Open Google
- Type PHP JSON
- hit Enter
- Click the 1st result
- Replace the values from PHP examples with [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) with your own values

Answer (score 0):

[json_encode](http://php.net/json-encode) will encode a PHP array as a JSON array.

As the exmaple on that link shows:

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);

// {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```